# VBA code to reference my inbox in my archive - CLOSED

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have this code which I can used to get to any folder in my primary inbox or inbox subfolder.

Does anyone know how to reference my archive folders or sent items? The archive folder is saved as "My Personal Folders"

Thank you very much

```
Sub ListAllItems()

    Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder, CurrUser As String
    Dim EmailItemCount As Integer, i As Integer, EmailCount As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Subject"
    Cells(1, 2).Formula = "Recieved"
    Cells(1, 3).Formula = "Attachments"
    Cells(1, 4).Formula = "Recipients"
    Cells(1, 5).Formula = "SenderName"
    With Range("A1:F1").Font
        .Bold = True
        .Size = 14
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set OLF = GetObject("", _
    "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Toastmasters")
    EmailItemCount = OLF.Items.Count
    i = 0: EmailCount = 0
     ' read e-mail information
    While i < EmailItemCount
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 50 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "Reading e-mail messages " & _
        Format(i / EmailItemCount, "0%") & "..."
        With OLF.Items(i)
            EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 1).Formula = .subject
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 2).Formula = Format(.ReceivedTime, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 3).Formula = .Attachments.Count
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 4).Formula = Not .UnRead
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 4).Formula = .Recipients.Count
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 5).Formula = .SenderName

        End With
    Wend
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Set OLF = Nothing
    Columns("A:F").AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**2st.** To set reference to any of archive folders you should set it as follows:

```
Set OLF = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("My Personal Folders")
```

where, optionally, instead of 'name' of the folder you could use index number (usually 2 and more if you have more archives).

**1st.** I'm not sure what you mean by 'sent items'. Are you asking about Folder with sent items:

```
Set OLF = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFoldersSentMail)
```

Comment: That's great! So, if you consider your question is solved you can always mark any correct answer as `accepted` to inform other that you are ok with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access folders in a secondary store, either use Namespace.Stores collection and then Store.GetRootFolder to access the top level folder of the store. Its MAPIFolder.Folders collection can be used to drill further down.

You can also Namespace.Folders collection to access the top level folders of all stores.

Answer (score 0):

If the earlier answers meet your needs then they will probably be easier to implement than this answer.

I use the routines below find a specified folder within the hierarchy.  I hope you find the instructions at the top of the first routine adequate.

```
Public Sub FindSelectedFolder(ByRef FolderTgt As MAPIFolder, _
                              ByVal NameTgt As String, ByVal NameSep As String)

  ' This routine (and its sub-routine) locate a folder within the hierarchy and
  ' returns it as an object of type MAPIFolder

  ' NameTgt   The name of the required folder in the format:
  '              FolderName1 NameSep FolderName2 [ NameSep FolderName3 ] ...
  '           If NameSep is "|", an example value is "Personal Folders|Inbox"
  '           FolderName1 must be an outer folder name such as
  '           "Personal Folders". The outer folder names are typically the names
  '           of PST files.  FolderName2 must be the name of a folder within
  '           Folder1; in the example "Inbox".  FolderName2 is compulsory.  This
  '           routine cannot return a PST file; only a folder within a PST file.
  '           FolderName3, FolderName4 and so on are optional and allow a folder
  '           at any depth with the hierarchy to be specified.
  ' NameSep   A character or string used to separate the folder names within
  '           NameTgt.
  ' FolderTgt On exit, the required folder.  Set to Nothing if not found.

  ' This routine initialises the search and finds the top level folder.
  ' FindSelectedSubFolder() is used to find the target folder within the
  ' top level folder.

  Dim InxFolderCrnt As Long
  Dim NameChild As String
  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim TopLvlFolderList As Folders

  Set FolderTgt = Nothing   ' Target folder not found

  Set TopLvlFolderList = _
          CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders

  ' Split NameTgt into the name of folder at current level
  ' and the name of its children
  Pos = InStr(NameTgt, NameSep)
  If Pos = 0 Then
    ' I need at least a level 2 name
    Exit Sub
  End If
  NameCrnt = Mid(NameTgt, 1, Pos - 1)
  NameChild = Mid(NameTgt, Pos + 1)

  ' Look for current name.  Drop through and return nothing if name not found.
  For InxFolderCrnt = 1 To TopLvlFolderList.Count
    If NameCrnt = TopLvlFolderList(InxFolderCrnt).Name Then
      ' Have found current name. Call FindSelectedSubFolder() to
      ' look for its children
      Call FindSelectedSubFolder(TopLvlFolderList.Item(InxFolderCrnt), _
                                            FolderTgt, NameChild, NameSep)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

End Sub
Public Sub FindSelectedSubFolder(FolderCrnt As MAPIFolder, _
                      ByRef FolderTgt As MAPIFolder, _
                      ByVal NameTgt As String, ByVal NameSep As String)

  ' See FindSelectedFolder() for an introduction to the purpose of this routine.
  ' This routine finds all folders below the top level

  ' FolderCrnt The folder to be seached for the target folder.
  ' NameTgt    The NameTgt passed to FindSelectedFolder will be of the form:
  '               A|B|C|D|E
  '            A is the name of outer folder which represents a PST file.
  '            FindSelectedFolder() removes "A|" from NameTgt and calls this
  '            routine with FolderCrnt set to folder A to search for B.
  '            When this routine finds B, it calls itself with FolderCrnt set to
  '            folder B to search for C.  Calls are nested to whatever depth are
  '            necessary.
  ' NameSep    As for FindSelectedSubFolder
  ' FolderTgt  As for FindSelectedSubFolder

  Dim InxFolderCrnt As Long
  Dim NameChild As String
  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim Pos As Long

  ' Split NameTgt into the name of folder at current level
  ' and the name of its children
  Pos = InStr(NameTgt, NameSep)
  If Pos = 0 Then
    NameCrnt = NameTgt
    NameChild = ""
  Else
    NameCrnt = Mid(NameTgt, 1, Pos - 1)
    NameChild = Mid(NameTgt, Pos + 1)
  End If

  ' Look for current name.  Drop through and return nothing if name not found.
  For InxFolderCrnt = 1 To FolderCrnt.Folders.Count
    If NameCrnt = FolderCrnt.Folders(InxFolderCrnt).Name Then
      ' Have found current name.
      If NameChild = "" Then
        ' Have found target folder
        Set FolderTgt = FolderCrnt.Folders(InxFolderCrnt)
      Else
        'Recurse to look for children
        Call FindSelectedSubFolder(FolderCrnt.Folders(InxFolderCrnt), _
                                            FolderTgt, NameChild, NameSep)
      End If
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  ' If NameCrnt not found, FolderTgt will be returned unchanged.  Since it is
  ' initialised to Nothing at the beginning, that will be the returned value.

End Sub
```